# @@RowCount inside Try Block not returning correct values --Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I have a `stored procedure` which deletes Records from the table if a given record exists.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_DTEST]
@CfgKey   AS VARCHAR(100)  
AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   BEGIN TRY
     BEGIN TRAN
    --Deletes ConfigSetting table if data exists
    IF EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[ConfigSetting]
    WHERE CfgKey  = @CfgKey
     AND RowStatus = 'A'
    )
    BEGIN
        DELETE 
        FROM [dbo].[ConfigSetting]
        WHERE  CfgKey  = @CfgKey
          AND RowStatus = 'A' 
    END


    IF @@ERROR = 0
             BEGIN
                  SELECT 'Number of Records Deleted : '+ CAST(@@rowcount AS varchar(10))
                  COMMIT TRAN;
              END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
             SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR, ERROR_LINE() AS [Error Line], ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [Error Message] 
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END CATCH

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

the `stored procedure`  runs fine. But when I execute the sp `@@rowcount` always returns `0` . If i put `@@rowcount` above the `error handling` block, it returns 1. why is that? is there any syntax error in this `query`?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any triggers (with on DELETE) on `[dbo].[ConfigSetting]`?

Comment: There's no syntax error. It's just that `@@ROWCOUNT` is telling you how many rows were affected by the last statement which, in the case of an if statement like that, is 0. The same would be true if you did something like `select * from myTable; if 1 = 1 select @@rowcount`. 1 = 1 affects no rows, therefore a row count of 0.

Comment: no triggers @gofr1

Comment: @zlk. actually I deleted a record from dbo.configsetting. after the execution of sp i got   'number of records deleted : 0'  as  output message. But 1 record got deleted from the table

Comment: Indeed, because @@ROWCOUNT is evaluating how many rows were affected by `@@ERROR = 0`, not your delete statement. Which is why if you have it before the IF statement, it would work. To be honest, I don't really think you need the if @@error statement anyway. If it reaches the point where you're selecting the rowcount, it hasn't errored. If an error occurs, it'd exit the try block and go to the catch block.

Comment: ok. thanks for the explanation. But i am still not clear about how many rows were affected by @@ERROR = 0. does @error = 0 means, the records which were successfully deleted? or this if statement reset it? Also for returning deleted row count, we must put a select @@rowcount statement right after the delete statement is it?

Comment: The if statement messes up the @@ROWCOUNT. @@ROWCOUNT isn't meant to be used inside an if statement. The if statement itself (regardless of the conditions, whether it be `IF @@ERROR = 0` or `IF 'hello kitty meow meow' <> 'woof, I am a dog'`) is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this demo. You should store `@@rowcount` immediately after delete. As  ZLK said in his comment `@@rowcount` will be reset by any other Sql statement including IF.

```
create table demo (n int);
insert demo(n) values (1), (2);
declare  @rc int =-1;

delete from demo where n=1;
set @rc = @@rowcount;
if (@@error = 0) -- this will reset @@rowcount
  select @rc, @@rowcount -- returns  1,  0
```